# Botón eliminar en java con procedimientos almacenados

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedure

Estoy actualmente haciendo un proyecto con procedimientos almacenados en MYSQL, solo que en el botón eliminar, no me elimina los registros en la base de datos, me aparece el siguiente error:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es el siguiente error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'
```

Mis procedimiento almacenados de eliminar:

```
delimiter //
create procedure eliminarUsuario(in id_usuari int)
begin
DELETE FROM usuario where id=id_usuario;
end //
```

el id lo estoy guardando temporalmente en un Textfield invisible y así es como tengo mi botón de eliminar:

```
Connection conn = null;

        try{
            conn = getConection();
            ps = conn.prepareCall("call eliminarUsuario(?)");
            ps.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(txtId.getText()));

            int res = ps.executeUpdate();

            if(res > 0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Datos eliminados..");
                limpiarcajas();
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al eliminar los datos..");
                limpiarcajas();
            }
            conn.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e);

        }
```

Comment: El error es claro, tu tabla usuario no tiene un campo id.